# Behaviour of the `virtual` keyword in C++ on objects instead of pointers

Tags: c++, virtual

I was trying to understand virtual functions.

Consider the following code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Animal 
{
public:
     virtual void eat() 
    {
        std::cout << "I eat like a generic animal.\n";
    }

};

class Wolf : public Animal 
{
public:
    void eat() 
    {
        std::cout << "I eat like a wolf!\n";
    }
};


int main() 
{

  Animal      a;
  Wolf        w;

  a.eat();
  w.eat();
```

}

With the `virtual` keyword I get the output

```
I eat like a generic animal.
I eat like a wolf!
```

as it should.

But If I remove the virtual keyword I still get the same output! From my 
elementary understanding of virtual functions, without the `virtual` I should have got the output

```
I eat like a generic animal.
I eat like a generic animal.
```

Is there anything elementary here I am missing  ?

I am using the g++ compiler on Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Polymorphism works by identifying the type of object that an instance actually refers to.**

In your case, your actual animals are as follows:

```
Animal      a;  //a is an animal.
Wolf        w;  //w is a wolf.
```

---

**So, you're not using polymorphism at all.**

What you need to do is more like this:

```
//Create a couple animal pointers.
Animal* a;
Animal* b;

//Create an animal instance and have a point to it.
a = new Animal();

//Create a wolf instance and have b point to it.
b = new Wolf();

//Calls Animal::eat as a is an animal.
a->eat();

//Calls Wolf::eat as a is a wolf.
b->eat();
```

---

**Note that you can use pointers or references to achieve this use of polymorphism.**

That is why you should usually pass objects by const-reference when working with class types.

```
//Will call Animal::eat or Wolf::eat depending on what animal was created as.
void foo(const Animal& animal) {
    animal.eat();
}

//Will always call Animal::eat and never Wolf::eat since this isn't a reference or
//a pointer.  Will also "slice" a Wolf object.
void foo(Animal animal) {
    animal.eat();
}
```

Note that slicing means it will turn a more derived class (wolf) into a less derived copy of that class (animal) indiscriminately which can be very misleading and unexpected.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, especially the second point. Though I am no expert, by the looks of it, that seems to be a misfeature. Also, why does C++ implement polymorphism only through pointers and reference as you say ?

Comment: @smilingbuddha: C++ will use the most derived version of a function known at compile time, unless the function is virtual.  Then it checks at compile time.  It's not that C++ is not doing polyphorphism, it's that _you_ aren't.  You say "This is a wolf" and told it how a wolf eats, and it did that.  If you wanted animal behavior, you have to tell it to treat the wolf as an animal.  Which is best done through pointers and references.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's a right behavior. Virtual functions are needed to introduce polymorphism. To enable polymorph behavior, you need to use pointers like this:

```
 Animal * a = new Animal();
 Animal * w = new Wolf();

 a->eat();
 w->eat();

 <...>

 delete a;
 delete w;
```

Provided the way you have it now, the behavior is right, because both variables clearly have different types.

Answer (score 1):

It's still a method even without the virtual. The virtual keyword allows polymorphic behavior in cases like this:

```
Animal* wolf = new Wolf; // I eat like a wolf! (as long as eating is virtual)
```

By using the virtual keyword you are telling to compiler to choose the appropriate implementation to call at run time based on the derived type.